# Realated to React

Tags: reactjs, deployment, frontend, react-fullstack, cortana-skills-kit

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 3:0-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Web D\Project\Real time chat\src'
Did you mean './firebase'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Web D\Project\Real time chat\node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.


ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 4:0-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/auth' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Web D\Project\Real time chat\src'


ERROR in ./src/pages/Register.js 6:0-63

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/auth' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Web D\Project\Real time chat\src\pages'
```

I am not accesing the authentication from firebase

Comment: What bundler do you use? Show your `package.json`